# How to go about building an RTSP server using Indy components?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, rtsp, indy, indy10

I would like to provide a stream of images via RTSP using Indy 10 components. I don't need to know all the individual requests and all, that's all covered separate from what I need. But what Indy component should I use and how should I use it? This stream will not consist of sound, only images.

Note that RTSP is very similar to HTTP, but with a different structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indy does not have any RTSP or RTP/RTCP components, so you will have to implement those protocols from scratch. RTSP is a textual-based protocol, so you can use `TIdCmdTCPServer`, though it may be better to derive from `TId(Custom)TCPServer` and override its `DoExecute()` method to avoid duplicated code (reading headers, processing URLs, etc), like `TIdHTTPServer` does. As for the images, you can use `TIdUDPClient` to send the RTP/RTCP packets as needed.

Comment: I'm disappointed there are no good sources for building an RTSP server in Delphi :( I'll be coming back with more questions about this, but I can already tell it's a mad task for me, knowing barely anything about Networking, Indy, RTSP, HTTP, RTP, etc. Is there any way you can provide a raw sample implementation at least to the point of handling individual requests / responses? I have two empty objects `TRTSPRequest` and `TRTSPResponse` and an event `TRTSPRequestEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; Request: TRTSPRequest; Response: TRTSPResponse; var Handled: Boolean) of object;` so far.

Comment: Or I will actually ask a new question, but will be a bit more prepared first.